# Bootstrap 4: Inline-forms button height

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Im working on a "Mock" facebook clone and im trying to do a simple "log in" form in the navbar.

I have it working pretty decent so far however the "Log in" submit button is floating much higher than the other items:

[image]

So it's looking ok but Im guessing the button is going where the "labels" normally go.

Here is my code thus far:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
      <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), class: "form-inline") do |f| %>
        <div class="field field form-group mb-2">
          <%= f.label :email %><br />
          <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <div class="field field form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
          <%= f.label :password %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <div class="actions mb-2">
          <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

It was kind of frustrating to wrap everything in an `li` and the whole group in a `ul` I can't tell if that's 100% necessary...but it's the only thing that would work.

I suppose I could adjust the `margin-top` by some % but im sure there is a cleaner obvious way Im missing.

Comment: Might be best to add an empty label. ex `<label>&nbsp;</label><br />` above the `.btn`. This will have consistent spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, you should not be wrapping your form inside a li tag and then ending it outside that li, try this, just change this code to your erb tags, running this with regular html for displaying it

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="field field form-group mb-2">
            <label for="email">Email</label><br />
            <input type="email" class="form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="field field form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
            <label for="password">Password</label><br /><br />
            <input type="password" class="form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="actions form-group mb-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```